# Encrypting search index using EFS

Tags: windows, encryption, windows-search, efs

Is there anything wrong with encrypting the search index with EFS while letting the search service index encrypted files? I've encrypted the directory %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Search and I've added SYSTEM user by using "cipher /ADDUSER 
/certhash:"SYSTEMHASH" /s:thedirectory, and it looks like the SYSTEM account has no problem indexing my files.

However, the recommendation tells me to only index encrypted files when a full-disk encryption is used. Is this a wrong practice?

Comment: @user110236: With EFS, in this particular case, the key *cannot* be entered, since *LocalSystem* does not log in interactively, therefore the EFS keys belonging to this system account are only obfuscated; they also are accessible by any Administrator as #2 says. With BitLocker, you always provide the decryption key before Windows can boot, so even though it doesn't protect against rogue Admins, it works fine against physical attacks by outsiders.

Comment: @grawity: You said, "With BitLocker, you always provide the decryption key before Windows can boot." I used the SysKey utility "to configure a start-up password that must be entered to decrypt the system key so that Windows can access the SAM database." Isn't that the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the reasoning for not just encrypting just the index in this [TechNet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744700(WS.10).aspx#WS_EncryptingtheIndex)

> **Encrypting the Index**
>   To encrypt the
>   index file itself, we recommend that
>   you encrypt the entire volume
>   containing the index with BitLocker or
>   another 3rd party full-volume
>   encryption option. This provides
>   strong protection against offline
>   attacks; online attacks are still
>   possible by users with administrator
>   access. BitLocker Drive Encryption
>   provides enhanced protection against
>   data theft by encrypting data
>   operating system and data volumes. In
>   Windows 7, BitLocker Drive Encryption
>   works on removable drives. We strongly
>   recommend also BitLocking operating
>   system volumes if you BitLock data
>   volumes.
>
> While the Encrypting File System (EFS)
>   can also be used, it is not
>   recommended. The Windows Search
>   service runs under the LocalSystem
>   account and needs access to the index
>   files. As a result, EFS keys
>   associated with the LocalSystem
>   account must be used to encrypt the
>   index files. Consequently, the index
>   files are open to the following
>   attacks:
>
> - Online: Any administrative user can
>     gain access to the encrypted index
>     files by simply impersonating the
>     LocalSystem account. (Existing tools
>     on the web make this a trivial task.)
> - Offline: The key that is used by the
>     LocalSystem account to decrypt files
>     is stored on the machine in an
>     obfuscated state. Someone with
>     physical access to the machine can use
>     existing tools on the web to retrieve
>     this key and access the encrypted
>     index files.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't really upvote you for the lack of reputation though :/